# Average of a collection of numbers equals the greatest of such numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to know the answer to this question: Suppose $a_1$, $a_2$, ... , $a_n$ are non-negative numbers so that $M$ is the greatest of such numbers. Is it true that if the average of $a_1$, $a_2$, ... , $a_n$ equals $M$, then every $a_i =M$?

I am sure it is true. If some $a_i$ were not equal to $M$, then $a_i < M$ (since $M$ is the greatest), and since all other $a_j \le M$, then $a_1 + ... + a_n < M + ... + M = nM$, so $\frac{a_1 + ... + a_n}{n} < M$, and the number on the left is the average of $a_1$, $a_2$, ... , $a_n$.

Is this correct???
Thank you

Comment: Ys, your proof is correct.

Comment: Your proof is correct.  I can't really say more.  I *want* to say "Obviously if you have someone below average you have have someone above average to compensate".  But as math is not about common sense.

Comment: @fleablood law of averages.

Answer (score 1):

Write the sequence as $$S = a_{1}, a_{2},a_{3},...,a_{n-1},M$$ where M is the maximum of $S$. Then the average $A$ of $S$ is 
$$A = \frac{a_{1} + a_{2} +.... + a_{n-1}+M}{n}$$ So then $$M = nA - a_{1} - a_{2} - ....-a_{n-1}$$
Lets set our 2 formulas for the maximum and the average together such that 
$$A = M$$ 
$$\frac{a_{1} + a_{2} +....+ a_{n-1} + M}{n} = nA - a_{1} - a_{2} - ....-a_{n-1} $$ 
$$a_{1} + a_{2} +....+ a_{n-1} + M = n^{2}A - na_{1} - na_{2} -....-na_{n-1}$$ $$M=n^{2}A - (n-1)a_{1} - (n-1)a_{2} -....-(n-1)a_{n-1}$$
Now lets get $A$ in terms of $M$ 
$$M=n^{2}(\frac{a_{1} + a_{2} +.... + a_{n-1}+M}{n}) - (n-1)a_{1} - (n-1)a_{2} -....-(n-1)a_{n-1} $$ 
$$M = (na_{1} + na_{2} +... + Mn + na_{n-1}) - (n-1)a_{1} - (n-1)a_{2} -....-(n-1)a_{n-1}$$ 
$$M = Mn - a_{1} - a_{2} -....-a_{n-1}$$
$$M(n-1) = a_{1} + a_{2} +...+a_{n-1}$$
$$M = \frac{a_{1} + a_{2} +...+a_{n-1}}{n-1}$$
So, if the average and maximum of the set are to be equal, then the maximum must be the average of all of the other elements. The only way for this to be true is if each element is equal to $M$, so yes, you are correct.

Comment: The basic premise of your answer is not correct. The average of $n$ values is their sum divided by $n$. Thus, for $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_n$, the average, as stated in the question, is $\frac{a_1 + \ldots + a_n}{n}$. Your basic idea is reasonable, but you're using a denominator of $2$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Whoops! Let me try to fix that...

Comment: It's better, but in your second last equation line, on the right side, you forgot to multiply $M$ by $n$. If you do this, you will get your last line starting with "$M = nM$", to end up with the average of the terms from $a_1$ to $a_{n-1}$ being $M$ instead of them summing to $0$.

Comment: Ok it looks like I think I finally got it right. Let me know if anything else is missing. thanks for the corrections!